# How can we authenticate mobile clients that send request to server

Tags: android, api, authentication, google-api, client-server

I am developing an mobile (Android) API that connects to my server and fetch a few data and send it to the mobile (Android) app that use this API.

I want to be sure that, only persons who has been authenticated with my servers can use the API.

I can give them a user name or password to use the API but what if someone else use the user name and password and send same request to my server(Reply attack). How can I avoid this attack on my API?

I have seen that google use an API key on his APIs like direction that is associated with a digest of signing key; but I am not sure how it is working and whether something like that can help me or not?

Actually I want to be sure that the client APPLICATION that is requesting to the server is the same APPLICATION that I myself has been developed it (not a decompiled and recompiled version of my app).Does some one knows some standard way to authenticate the users of API?

Comment: i dont really get what kind of attack you are going to prevent ? a person who have username and password can call all your APIs that is how it must be. if you want to ensure that the data is not altered in the middle (man-in-the-middle attack) i can show you how. if you want to prevent frequent api calls attack there is another way to solve it that i can tell if you want

Comment: in `man in the middle attack` attacker can steel your user's username and password that you can prevent this. is that what you want ?

Comment: We past man in the middle with encrypting the sending content. But suppose that some one decompile the mobile app, find username and password and send new request to my app using the username and password- Actually I want to be sure that the client APP that is requesting to me is the same APP that I myself has been developed it (not another app that decompiled my code and recompiled it)

Comment: if some one decompiles the app he can just see the content in that particular device that is surely his own device. he is going to steal his own username password which already has ?

Comment: oh you want to ensure that the only application which send request is your own application ?

Comment: This is an API that will embed into an mobile app. the developer who use the API should hardcode the username and password of the API into the code

Comment: so you have something like a sdk that lets other developers use your APIs ?

Comment: yes, I have an aar file that other developers use this

Comment: look i think were both persian. i have done something like you want in Mobazi application in Iran. this is the best way existing. i searched for one year. it cant be completely safe but this way is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

so from what you explained i assume you want to ensure that only Applications you want should be able to use server APIs.

there is not any complete way to ensure this but some steps can make a great protection:

1- you must have a complete list of packagenames which are allowed to send you request

2- you must proguard your sdk code (the aar file you said) and take the username password of developers from out of this `aar` so there would be no need for developers to know about codes inside the aar something like below:

YourSdkMainClass theInstance = YourSdkMainClass.getInstance("username","password");

3- you must get the application packagename and send it along with username and password every time you call any API (making a encrypted string out of three would be great) - or you can choose a mechanism where you generate a hash token out of these three on a specific API that is called at the beginning of the application and use that token for calling other APIs after that (the token must be invalidated after some hours of not using and new token should be generating)

4- at the server side you must check the received packageName and compare it with the packageName (or list of packageNames) allowed for that specific developer. if everything is OK then response to API call (or send back the token)

NOTE: this scenario can be improved sending the signature of APK instead of packageName. using signature key, multiple apps with same packageName wont be able to send request to the server. of course you need to have signature of the APKs of your developers in server side (ask them when you want to give them the user password)

but all these are perfect if you proguard the `aar` in a good way.

Comment: The proguard apk or library can also be reverse engineered. Imagine that someone decomplie the arr(or in similar case the apk) and find the logic of the aar and then recreate another aar just like my arr. The attacker also have the user name and and password(by decompiling the app of developer who use my aar) so he can send a fake request to the server

Comment: look bro, this is the best you can do trust me. no other way exist. No its not that easy you think. if you progaurd (not keeping important classes from proguarding) it will be so hard for anyone to find what you send and how you encrypt them. try not to hardcode any string try to use char arrays for all important strings.

Comment: if the person using your sdk tries to attack he can do with the same apk and signature because you let him in. this is the best way to limit attack. there is no such a mechanism to let some one in and then say no you cant use this api in this way. your API layer (server code) must be so safe by itself.

Comment: the scenario i gave is just to make sure some specific packagename and signature is using your APIs but in real words this concepts is not practical. you either let some one use the api or you dont.
if the apk should be validated it has just one ID, and that is signature of apk ;)